# How do you add photo to correct index in a Ruby on Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, indexing

I currently have a Ruby on Rails app where I can upload a photo and a number.

```
<%= form_for(@masterpiece) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :user_piece %><br>
  <%= f.file_field :user_piece %><br>
  <%= f.label :piece_number %><br>
  <%= f.number_field :piece_number %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

When the photo uploads, it goes to an unordered list of items.

```
  <ul>
    <% @masterpieces.each do |masterpiece| %>
      <li><%=image_tag masterpiece.user_piece.url(:square) %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

However, I want there to be a grid of 4 rows and 5 pictures per row.  I would like the image to upload to the correct number index in the li.  I'm not sure how to go about this.  Do I need to make 20 predetermined li's and then match the index number with the piece number?

My guess is I need to determine the index in the model.  However, I am not sure if I make to pre-determined li's.

```
  # do I need to make predetermined li's?

  def determine_index
    # take the piece_number
    # have piece number correlate to index
  end
```

Then I'm guessing in the controller I need to write an if else statement similar to this. I only made an example for the first 3.

```
  def create
    @masterpiece = Masterpiece.new(masterpiece_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @masterpiece.save
        index_placement = @masterpiece.determine_placement
        if index_placement == 1
          # put in the first li
        elsif index_placement == 2
          # putin the second li
        else
          # put in the 3rd li
        end
        format.html { redirect_to masterpieces_url }
      else
        format.html { render :index }
      end
    end
  end
```

Rails v 4.1.4.
Using paperclip and aws-sdk to upload photos as a side note.

Comment: All the piece_numbers are unique and you want to align them according to their piece_numbers?

Comment: Not all of them are unique. V2 is that you can upload multiple to each section and then it will loop through all of the uploads every second.

Answer (score 1):

In my question, I think I could've been more clear that I needed to have 20 predetermined boxes in the grid.  These predetermined boxes will filled with a default image.  Once a user uploads a photo to one of the grids, it will cycle through each photo. In this question and answer, I will focus solely on setting up the grid.

The default image in this case is just "foo".

I set up a hash of image_urls.  For now, the default image will just be "foo" since I didn't want to add links to my s3 bucket on Stackoverflow.

Then I loop over all of the pieces of the masterpiece.
In this loop, I am shoveling the image into the pre-determined hash dependent on the key value of the hash, which directly correlates to the piece number.

masterpieces_controller.rb

```
  def index
    image_urls = {
      1 => ["foo"],
      2 => ["foo"],
      3 => ["foo"],
      4 => ["foo"],
      5 => ["foo"],
      6 => ["foo"],
      7 => ["foo"],
      8 => ["foo"],
      9 => ["foo"],
      10 => ["foo"],
      11 => ["foo"],
      12 => ["foo"],
      13 => ["foo"],
      14 => ["foo"],
      15 => ["foo"],
      16 => ["foo"],
      17 => ["foo"],
      18 => ["foo"],
      19 => ["foo"],
      20 => ["foo"],
    }

    Masterpiece.all.each do |masterpiece|
      image_urls[masterpiece.piece_number] << masterpiece.user_piece.url(:square)
    end

    @image_urls = image_urls
  end
```

In the view, I am continuing to use the each_slice method.

```
  <ul>
  <% @image_urls.each_slice(5) do |row| %>
    <% row.each do |_, urls| %>
      <li class="square-image" data-urls=<%= urls.to_json %>>
        <span class="user-image"><%= image_tag(urls.sample) %></span>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Nice. You should also automate that image_urls hash.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to make 20 predetermined li's and then match the index number with the piece number?

Looking at your question i think all the piece_numbers are unique and fixed(20) so to show them in grids you can do something like this:

a. **Order your Masterpiece records by piece_number:**

```
@masterpieces = Masterpiece.order("piece_number") #this will order them in ascending order by the piece_number field in your table
```

b. **In your index action slice your records by 5 and show them up:**

```
<% @masterpieces.each_slice(5) do |slice| %>
 <ul class="clearfix">
    <% slice.each do |masterpiece| %>
      <li class="pull-left"><%=image_tag masterpiece.user_piece.url(:square) %></li>
    <% end %>
 </ul>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I believe this cuts it down into columns, but not into rows. Additionally, if there is a missing number ( i.e. I enter 5 but there is no 4 ), the 5 will fill in the 4.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Lauren just needed some css and html love to make them into columns, i have used bootstrap classes so if you aren't using bootstrap then let me know will update my answer with styles. For your second problem can you explain why you need to fill them in their position only, i mean if no. 4 doesn't have content then it'll just leave a blank container which will automatically won't show up as there is no content inside it. Also can you explain a bit more about V2

Comment: Thanks for your help Mandeep. I figured it all out! Below is my answer to the Rails portion and here is another post indicating how I got the second portion to work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878916/how-do-you-nest-a-map-method-inside-a-map-method-using-jquery-json-and-custom-d